# (jQuery to Vue.js) Dynamic element event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Found out about vue.js and would like to rewrite some part of my jQuery code to vue. My problem is about handling the elements that are dynamically created.

If it was being written on jQuery, .on() on a parent element would work. Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Vue.js

I found a similar case here: http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/151/vue-js-not-listening-to-dynamically-created-elements/4

**evan** the creator replied:

> You can't, because Vue doesn't work this way. Use v-if and components, don't add HTML on the fly.

I did not get it and can't find any help regarding this. Rewriting everything to vue would take a lot of time. Would like jQuery and vue to work together.

Again, How do I handle events of elements that are being created dynamically?

Comment: What creates an element in jQuery at the moment? You might be able to create the elements already and like Evan said use `v-if` to only show them when certain state is matched like you have in jQuery at the moment

Comment: Provide some code example first, please.